# Jira User-Status dashboard?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I was trying to find some extension (or maybe built-in functionality) for Jira which would allow to assign a status to a user like it is possible in popular messengers, e.g. "on vacation" or "doing home-office today". It would be great to see a dashboard with statuses of all users displayed together.

The only thing which sounds close to what I'm searching for is 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/conf54/confluence-user-s-guide/sharing-content/user-status-updates 
but that one is for Confluence and we don't use Confluence in our workflow, we have Jira and Wiki so answers like "just use Confluence" won't work.

Is there such a thing, but for Jira?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, but : There is **no such thing** for *JIRA* (atleast for now).

Just because Atlassian provides a possibility to ***connect JIRA with Confluence:***
https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/integrating-jira-and-confluence-2825.html

As far as I know they have no intentions to bring Confluence type things in JIRA, but don't quote me on that.
Sorry I couldn't give a positive answer.